# Behaviour of "#'" in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

As far as I understand `#' <object>` is an abbreviation for `(function <object>)`.

But I noticed different behaviour while using `#'` in apply function.

Example

```
(apply '+ '(1 2)) => Works and give 3
(apply (function +) '(1 2 ) ) => 3
```

However

```
(apply '# '(1 2)) => Err!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [reference](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm):

> The notation `#'name` may be used as an abbreviation for `(function name)`.

Note that the syntax used is `#'`,  not `'#`, which is just a way a quoting the symbol `#`, since `'a` is equivalent to `(quote a)`.

So you should use:

```
(apply #'+ '(1 2))
```

In general the character `#` followed by a character has a special meaning for inputting values. For instance `#\` is for reading characters (like in #\Space), `#(` for reading vectors, (like in `#(1 2 3)`), etc.

Comment: # is the default reader macro character, by convention. One could easily done the same with different starting char.

Answer (score 0):

The #' notation is implemented by the reader.

If you want to see the effect, you can for example use this:

```
CL-USER 1 > (read-from-string "#'+")
(FUNCTION +)
3

CL-USER 2 > '#'+
(FUNCTION +)
```